# OO PHP - child class not inheriting parent methods and properties

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have a very simple OO class structure and cannot get my head around why the child class is not inheriting the properties and methods from the parent.

This is a basic example of my set up:

```
//Main class:
class Main{

    //construct
    public function Main(){
        //get data from model
        $data = $model->getData();

        //Get the view
        $view = new View();

        //Init view
        $view->init( $data );

        //Get html
        $view->getHTML();
    }

}


//Parent View class
class View{

    public $data, $img_cache; 

    public function init( $data ){       
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->img_cache = new ImageCache();
    }

    public function getHTML(){

        //At this point all data is intact (data, img_cache)

        $view = new ChildView();

        //After getting reference to child class all data is null
        //I expected it to return a reference to the child class and be able to 
        //call the parent methods and properties using this object. 

        return $view->html();
    }

}


//Child View Class
class ChildView{

    public function html(){

        //I get a fatal error here: calling img_cache on a non-object.
        //But it should have inherited this from the parent class surely?

        return '<img src="'.$this->img_cache->thumb($this->data['img-src']).'"/>';       
    }
}
```

So I expected the child class to inherit the properties and methods from the parent. Then when I get a reference to the child class it should be able to use the `img_cache` object. But I get a fatal error here: `Call to a member function thumb() on a non-object`.

Where have I gone wrong with this?

Comment: You need to extend the subclass for it to inherit the parent's properties. http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Comment: `class ChildView extends View`

Comment: Your ChildView doesn't extend View. Why do you expect PHP to know it is a child of View?

Comment: There's something off with your OOP understanding. Do NOT create an object ChildView inside the View class. Instead, extend View and in your main controller call `new ChildView();`.

Comment: @MP_Webby please avoid editing your original question. In this way future readers will not know what is different between the original code and the answers.

Comment: @PEMapModder, yes I understand this. It was a typo, just making my question clearer. The subject of the question has not changed.

Comment: The subject did not change but editing the question makes the answer partially meaningless, so I rolled it back to revision 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the inheritance with extends the base class http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Try this for your child class

```
//Child View Class
class ChildView extends View{

    public function html(){

        //I get a fatal error here: calling img_cache on a non-object.
        //But it should have inherited this from the parent class surely?

        return '<img src="'.$this->img_cache->thumb($this->data['img-src']).'"/>';       
    }
}
```

Also as @ferdynator says, you are instantiating the parent, not the child, so your `Main` class also needs to be changed to instantiate `ChildView`, not the parent `View`

```
//Main class:
class Main{

    //construct
    public function Main(){
        //get data from model
        $data = $model->getData();

        //Get the view
        $view = new ChildView();

        //Init view
        $view->init( $data );

        //Get html
        $view->getHTML();
    }

}
```

Comment: Also the class `View` is called in `Main`, not `ChildView`.

Comment: Thanks @ferdynator. I forgot to add the `extend` in my example here (edited) but still have the original issue.

Comment: Yes I see. New-ish to OO / MVC so still getting my head around it. Answer marked as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a subclass by instantiating it. You make it `extends` the superclass.

Then you can make an abstract method in an abstract superclass (or make a default implementation if you don't want it to be abstract), and implement it in the subclass that `extends` the superclass by declaring a method with the same name.

```
//Main class:
class Main{

    //construct
    public function Main(){
        //get data from model
        $data = $model->getData();

        //Get the view
        $view = new ChildView(); // <--- changed

        //Init view
        $view->init( $data );

        //Get html
        $view->getHTML();
    }

}


//Parent View class
abstract class View{ // <--- changed

    public $data, $img_cache; 

    public function init( $data ){       
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->img_cache = new ImageCache();
    }

    public abstract function getHTML(); // <--- changed
}


//Child View Class
class ChildView extends View{ // <--- changed

    public function getHTML(){ // <--- changed

        //I get a fatal error here: calling img_cache on a non-object.
        //But it should have inherited this from the parent class surely?

        return '<img src="'.$this->img_cache->thumb($this->data['img-src']).'"/>';       
    }
}
```

In simple words, the child class and the parent class have the *same* instance. They just contain code from different classes, but they are still the same object. Only the same object can get the same properties.

BTW, use `__construct` for constructors (`public function __construct` instead of `public function Main`. Using the class name as the constructor name is very old-fashioned and is probably going to get deprecated (not sure if it already is).

Comment: Yea I forgot to add `extend`, just a typo. It is in my code but I still have an inheritance issue. Thanks @PEMapModder

Comment: I forgot to note one of the important changes I made. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40562917/revisions